# Reduce rounding error in SVD of a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, precision, svd

I have to do the SVD of a matrix, but it has some errors, in the following example `U[1][1]`, `U[2][1]` and `U[2][0]` should be `0`.

[image]

The thing is that the above example was only a test, I have to work with large matrices which won't be so well conditioned, what can I do to trust the results I'll get?

Answer (score 2):

By most standards `1e-17` is considered to be `0`.

For example, it passes the `np.allclose` test

```
In [582]: A=np.array([1,-1,1,1,1,1]).reshape(3,2)

In [583]: U,d,V=np.linalg.svd(A)

In [584]: U
Out[584]: 
array([[ -8.56248666e-17,   1.00000000e+00,  -6.40884929e-17],
       [ -7.07106781e-01,   2.53974359e-17,  -7.07106781e-01],
       [ -7.07106781e-01,   2.53974359e-17,   7.07106781e-01]])

In [585]: y=np.array([[0,np.sqrt(2),0],[-1,0,-1],[-1,0,1]])/np.sqrt(2)

In [586]: y
Out[586]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ],
       [-0.70710678,  0.        , -0.70710678],
       [-0.70710678,  0.        ,  0.70710678]])

In [587]: np.allclose(U,y)
Out[587]: True
```